# Extremely long build time in xcode on big array of maps using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am building an iOS app using xcode 7.2 and swift. The app uses a database consisting of an array of maps. It is a database over all elements (the array) and their corresponding isotopes (the maps within the array). In total the array is about 110 long and average map is about 23 long. So the total amount of entries is 2600. Building the project takes 20+ min. While the database is not small it shouldn't take that long to build the project, what is xcode doing?

Is it my syntax that is wrong or should i not be using an array of maps at all and try to go for a SQLite solution instead? Would that have a dramatic impact on the read speed of the database?

Here is an outtake of the code, it looks the same for the whole file:

```
struct DataBase {
var knownIsotopes = [[Int:IsotopeData]]()
init() {
    knownIsotopes.append([
        1 : IsotopeData(name: "\(Constants.elementSymbols[0])\(1)", decayMode: [IsotopeData.DecayMode.BetaMinus], Z: 0, A: 1, halfLife: 613.9)])
    knownIsotopes.append([
        1 : IsotopeData(name: "\(Constants.elementSymbols[1])\(1)", decayMode: [IsotopeData.DecayMode.Stable], Z: 1, A: 1, halfLife: -1),
        2 : IsotopeData(name: "\(Constants.elementSymbols[1])\(2)", decayMode: [IsotopeData.DecayMode.Stable], Z: 1, A: 2, halfLife: -1),
        3 : IsotopeData(name: "\(Constants.elementSymbols[1])\(3)", decayMode: [IsotopeData.DecayMode.BetaMinus], Z: 1, A: 3, halfLife: 388789632),
        4 : IsotopeData(name: "\(Constants.elementSymbols[1])\(4)", decayMode: [IsotopeData.DecayMode.NeutronEmission], Z: 1, A: 4, halfLife: 276),
        5 : IsotopeData(name: "\(Constants.elementSymbols[1])\(5)", decayMode: [IsotopeData.DecayMode.NeutronEmission], Z: 1, A: 5, halfLife: 342),
        6 : IsotopeData(name: "\(Constants.elementSymbols[1])\(6)", decayMode: [IsotopeData.DecayMode.NeutronEmission], Z: 1, A: 6, halfLife: 96)])
    knownIsotopes.append([
        3 : IsotopeData(name: "\(Constants.elementSymbols[2])\(3)", decayMode: [IsotopeData.DecayMode.Stable], Z: 2, A: 3, halfLife: -1),
        4 : IsotopeData(name: "\(Constants.elementSymbols[2])\(4)", decayMode: [IsotopeData.DecayMode.Stable], Z: 2, A: 4, halfLife: -1),
```

Comment: I recently had a similar problem. My issue was static dictionaries. You could try creating an empty one then in code add each - that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to place this data in a PList (which I agree is the best practice here), you could lighten the compiler's workload by making your initializer for IsotopeData a little smarter (or create a convenience init)

The string interpolation that you use to assemble the name is costly for the compiler and could be completely handled internally by the initializer given that it merely combines the element's symbol (a function of your element number Z) with the atomic mass (essentially the value of A: between parentheses).

Your convenience init could also accept a simple value for the decay mode instead of a one element array (it can make in an array internally).

Even if you have exceptions to this pattern farther down your data, reducing the load for the majority of entries should help.

The other thing that makes the compiler cringe is large "literal" dictionaries.  The example only shows a 6 entry dictionary but if you have some that are much bigger than that, you may want to initialize them differently.

All this should make the compiler's job a little easier and reduce compile time.

[EDIT] Example code to read from a pList in the app's bundle.

(add the pList to your project in xCode)

```
let myList = NSDictionary(fromBundleFileName:"myList.plist") as! [String:NSDictionary]
```

Depending on what you put in your pList, your code needs to use the dictionary appropriately (my example is a dictionary of dictionaries).  The first level of a pList is always a dictionary but you can chose from a variety of values for the keys (including nested dictionaries).

Note that pList are actually XML files so you could also produce the content using other tools if you respect their tag structure.

Comment: I reformatted the database into a plist instead and it works wonders. The compilation time is now around 1 second with no apparent impact on performance. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @GustafHolst Can you please show code for how to read from plist?

Comment: See the example under my [ EDIT ]